# Java public enum method purpose

Tags: java, enums

So I have my enum

```
public enum Sample {
   ValueA{
      @Override
   public String getValue(){ return "A"; }   
 },
 ValueB{
    @Override
   public String getValue(){ return "B"; }

   public void doSomething(){ }
 };
abstract public String getValue();
};
```

and I have some other code trying to use the enum.

```
Sample.ValueB.doSomething();
```

Which seems like it should be valid, but produces the error "The method doSomething() is undefined for the type Sample". As opposed to

```
Sample value = Sample.ValueB;
value.doSomething();
```

which produces the same error and seems reasonable.

I assume there is a reasonable answer as to why the first one doesn't work and it relates to the two examples being equivalent under the hood. I was hoping someone could point me towards the documentation on why it is that way.

Comment: It would really help if you'd say what error you're getting...

Comment: Shouldn't you call `Sample.doSomething()`?

Comment: @nfechner..the `doSomething()` method is not static..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type of the "field" `ValueA` is `Sample`. That means that you can only invoke methods on `ValueA` that `Sample` provides. From [JLS §8.9.1. Enum Constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1):

> Instance methods declared in these class bodies may be invoked outside the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in the enclosing enum type.

More importantly: From a design perspective `enum` values should be uniform: if some operation is possible with one specific value, then it should be possible with all values (although it might result in different code being executed).

Answer (score 10):

Basically the *compile-time type* of `Sample.ValueB` is still Sample, even though the *execution-time* type of the value will be `ValueB`. So your two snippets of code are equivalent - clients don't get to see the "extra" methods which are only present in *some* of your enum values.

You can effectively think of the enum as declaring a field like this:

```
public static final Sample ValueB = new Sample() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(){ return "B"; }

    public void doSomething(){ }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
enum Sample
{
     Value{
        public void doSomething()
        {
              //do something
        }
    };
}
```

you are not creating an instance of the `Sample` enum, rather an instance of an anonymous sub-class of the `enum Sample`. Thet's why the method `doSomething()` is undefined.

Update: this can be proved as follows:

Try this

```
System.out.println(Sample.ValueB.getClass().getName());
```

prints `Sample$2`

Which means that even though you have the method `doSomething()` in the instance of `Sample$2` which you have named `ValueB`, you are referring it through the super-class reference of type `Sample` and hence only those methods defined in the class `Sample` will be visible at compile time.

You can call that `doSomething()` at runtime via reflection though.

Comment: More importantly: the type of the "field" `Value` will **still** be `Sample` and *not* `Sample$1`.

Answer (score 3):

`public void doSomething(){ }` will have same effect as `private void doSomething(){ }`.

`doSomething()` is not visible outside ValueB unless you add `doSomething()` to the `Sample`.

Each `Sample` value has type `Sample`, so it cannot have different set of methods for different values (from outside perspective).

Comment: Warning: the `Sample` *values* **do** have more specific types if they have a class body. The `Sample` *fields* only ever have the type `Sample`.

Comment: @Joachim: sure, but those specific types are anonymous subclasses of Sample, so "outside" you can only use interface defined by Sample. I didn't make my self clear - sorry.